# Builder plugin how to display items selected by another model class instead of all items?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-builder

I build my own plugin with octoberCMS Builder plugin.
There are 2 different model classes

1. category
2. item

inside the model class "item" I have a relation to model class category so each item can be linked to a "category".

On my webpage, I would like to display model class category and inside all items from model class "item" that are linked to that category.

however, all items are displayed now instead of the ones linked to category.
My thought was to use the == sign but that's not working so far. 
How can I solve this issue? Help would be highly appreciated!

[explanation of my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urOnI.jpg)
 [what my page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBMEN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can utilize parent child relation ship.

> In your `Category` model add relationship

```
class Category extends Model
{
    // we consider item table has `category_id` field to maintain relationship  
    public $hasMany = [
        'items' => ['Yournamespace\Item']
    ];
}
```

> now all you can so is fetch `Categories`

```
$categories= Category::all();
// pass $categories to view
```

> now loop through `category` and `its items`

```
<ul>
    {% for category in categories%}
        <li>
            <h3> {{ category.name }} </h3>
            <ul>
                {% for item in category.items %}
                    <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It will `show list of categories` as **main list** and `each list have sub-list` as **it's items**

if any doubts please comment.